# What happens if the player does not touch home plate?

Tags: rules, baseball

The batter hits a home run and rounds the bases without touching home plate.

His teammates surround and touch him and he takes his helmet off and is halfway to the dugout when the fans and his coach yell at him to go back and touch home.

The opposing team appeals and the batter is called out. Is this correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens to the runner if he misses a base after hitting a homerun?](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3364/what-happens-to-the-runner-if-he-misses-a-base-after-hitting-a-homerun)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate; the answer is different for home plate than second base, because there is no subsequent base the runner needed to touch after home plate.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the batter did not touch home before the appeal was made, then yes, the batter would be called out. This falls under Rule 5.09(c)(4).

> Any runner shall be called out, on appeal, when he fails to touch home base and makes no attempt to return to that base, and home base is tagged.